# Why wasn't Evey recognized?

Tags: plot-explanation, v-for-vendetta

In [*V for Vendetta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_for_Vendetta_(film)), when V captures Evey and imprisons her in the makeshift prison that he created, he shaves her head and Evey is proven to have no fear.  When V releases her, he asks for her to return before November 5th.

Evey does return to V on November 5th and explains to him that she has been living undetected:

> But then, one day, I was at a market... ...and a friend, someone I had
>   worked with at the BTN, got in line behind me. I was so nervous that
>   when the cashier asked me for my money, I dropped it. My friend picked
>   it up... ...and handed it to me. She looked at me right in the eyes...
>   ...didn't recognize me. Whatever you did to me worked better than I'd
>   have imagined.

**What was Evey referring to when she said "Whatever you did to me worked better than I'd ever imagined"?  Was this referring to her not having fear anymore?  Was she also referring to her physical appearance due to her head being shaved?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

During the time Evey was

> *imprisoned* and questioned by a *masked unknown* policeman

V was *training her* (in fact torturing her, but it was a necessary sacrifice) so that at the end

> she chose death instead of revealing where V's hideout was to get her life saved.

So she was not afraid anymore of anything, not even death, **just like him**: do you remember the scene in which Evey comes out of the hideout? It is raining and she opens her arm and cries, just like V did when he escaped his prison.

So, to put it simply, she **had changed *deeply* inside** to the point former collegues and friend cannot recognize her.

One could say she has grown up.

---

**In the graphic novel** it is more complicated: V is actually training her to become the new V: his job is to destroy, Evey's is to build a new society based on anarchy (the good anarchy, not chaos, he was chaos).